# How to trigger 'this' within a loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I am kind-of new to react and having trouble getting value of a radio button generated from a loop. I have a fiddle set-up at: https://jsfiddle.net/rexonms/zrax0zfa/.

The example has two type of radio buttons. One group is generated using loop and the other one without loop. The one without loop works (logs the value of the button) but the ones created with the loop doesn't work when I try to console log the value of the radio button.

Thank you in advance.

```
var Inputs = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            radios: {
                a: { radio: 'Radio Loop A' },
                b: { radio: 'Radio Loop B' },
                c: { radio: 'Radio Loop C' }
            },

            radioNoLoop: 'Radio No Loop' 
        }
    },

    selectHandlerLoop: function(e){
        console.log(e.target.value);
    },

    selectHandle: function(e){
        console.log(e.target.value);
    },

    render: function() {
        var radios = this.state.radios;
        var r = this;
        return(
            <div>
                {/* Creating radio buttons using Array */}
                {Object.keys(radios).map(function(key,r) {
                    return ( 
                        <div key={key}>
                            <label forHTML={key}>
                                <input type="radio" name="loopTest" value={radios[key].radio} id={key} nChange={r.selectHandlerLoop} /> {radios[key].radio}
                            </label>
                        </div>

                    );
                })}

               <hr />
               {/* Radio button no array loop */}
               <label forHTML="noLoop">
                   <input type="radio" id="noLoop" value="noLoop" onChange={this.selectHandle}/> {this.state.radioNoLoop}
               </label>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<Inputs />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please explain the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

javascript map actually has functionality for what you're trying to do. you pass `this` to the second argument of map (after the callback):

```
{Object.keys(radios).map(function(key) {
  return ( 
    <div key={key}>
      <label forHTML={key}>
        <input type="radio" name="loopTest" value={radios[key].radio} id={key} onChange={this.selectHandlerLoop} /> {radios[key].radio}
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}, this)}
```

Comment: You need to update the onChange to use this.selectHandlerLoop instead or r.selectHandler.  Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zrax0zfa/4/

Answer (score 5):

Your problem has nothing to do with React. You seem to have a misunderstanding of how functions / closures work.

Lets look at that part:

```
Object.keys(radios).map(function(key,r) { ... });
```

This declares a function expecting two arguments, `key` and `r`, and passes it to `.map`. `.map` will call the function and provide the corresponding arguments.

If you look at the [`.map` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can see that `.map` passes three arguments to the callback:

> **callback**
>
> Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking three arguments:
>
> - `currentValue`: The current element being processed in the array.
> - `index`: The index of the current element being processed in the array.
> - `array`: The array map was called upon.

So what will the value of `r` be? It will be the **index** of the current element.

The **parameter** `r` has **nothing** to do with the **variable** `r` you declared with

```
var r = this;
```

If you want `r` *inside* the callback to refer to that variable, remove it from the parameter list

```
Object.keys(radios).map(function(key) { ... });
//                                  ^ no r
```

`r` is now a free variable inside the callback and will be looked up in higher scopes.

To learn more about closures, have a look at this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

---

We can simplify the mapping by using ES6 **arrow functions**, which you can use if you transpile your code with Babel or `jsx --harmony`:

```
{Object.keys(radios).map(key => 
  <div key={key}>
    <label forHTML={key}>
      <input ... nChange={this.selectHandlerLoop} /> {radios[key].radio}
    </label>
  </div>
)}
```

Because `this` inside *arrow functions* is lexically scoped, it will refer to the `this` value of the `render` method, which is your React component.