# managing the state of looped radio buttons in react

Tags: reactjs, array.prototype.map

So i have an API. I have to drill down into it, so i start by mapping over all the response data, then do another map inside of that to get an object (quiz answers). All of this has rendered fine. However, when you click one of the radio boxes, it does not switch from yes/no, instead they get clicked and stay clicked. Now i know how to handle this normally, with an onChange and set the state of item to true or false, but in this case, the items are being generated through a looped map.

How do i change their state when they are looped items?

The code:

```
        this.quizData = this.state.quiz_data.map((item, id) => {
            return (
                <div key={id}>
                    <h3 className='quiz-question'>{item.Title}</h3>
                    <p>{item.Question}</p>

                    <div className='quiz-answer-wrapper'>
                        <div className='quiz-answer-option'>
                                {this.quizAnswers = item.PreQualifyingAnswerDefinitions.map((item, id) => {
                                    return (
                                        <fieldset className='quiz-radio-label' key={id}>
                                            <input type='radio' value='value' onChange={() => value('')} />
                                                {item.Answer}
                                            </fieldset>
                                    )
                                })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
```

Comment: Hey does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401854/how-to-trigger-this-within-a-loop-in-react

Comment: I still need to fix the issue where if you have 4 radio buttons, all 4 will remain true when clicked, they wont switch between true/false.

Comment: In my answer I assumed you wanted only one radio button to remain active and the others to go inactive. Is this correct?

Comment: correct. but i loop through an api, lets say it returns 10 sets of yes/no answers. I need to create the same amount of radio buttons, and tie those two together, so each yes/no pair has a radio button associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the event handler parameter. Instead of overriding the `onChange` with `() => value('')`, instead pass `e => value(e)`. Alongside this give each radio input a `name`, this `name` gets passed with the event handler.

On a side note, I would use a different name for your `value` function, maybe something like `handleAnswerRadio`.

This [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) might help clear some things up.

Here is some code to show you working mapped radio inputs.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      radioInputs: [
        { name: 'radio_1', checked: false },
        { name: 'radio_2', checked: false },
        { name: 'radio_3', checked: false },
        { name: 'radio_4', checked: false },
        { name: 'radio_5', checked: false }
      ]
    }
  }
  
  handleAnswerRadio = (e) => {
    let newRadios = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.radioInputs))
    
    newRadios.map(item => {
      item.checked = item.name === e.target.name
      return item
    })
    
    this.setState({
      radioInputs: newRadios
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.radioInputs.map((item, index) => (
          <div>
            {item.name}
            <input key={item.name} name={item.name} type="radio"
                   checked={item.checked}
                   onChange={e => this.handleAnswerRadio(e)}/>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render((<App/>), document.getElementById('testing'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing"></div>
```

Comment: So i need to loop through my api data, that has the answers for each of these radio buttons, and add them into the radioInputs state array, correct?

Comment: Yes that should work, as long as you have a unique name/id for each answer. I would also make each answer an object so that you can store a "checked" boolean as you can see in my example.